# BackboneJS form handling

Tags: forms, backbone.js, coffeescript

I need to set up a simple CRUD app using BackboneJS (using CoffeeScript)

Can't seem to be able to handle a simple form from inside my view.

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="code">Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in my view I have:

```
define [
  'jquery'
  'underscore'
  'backbone'
  'templates'
], ($, _, Backbone, JST) ->
  class SimpleView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/simple.hbs']

    events:
      'submit': 'submit'

    render: ->
      $('.content').html(@template())

    submit: (event) ->
      console.log 'submit', event
      @$('input[name=title]').val()


  view = new SimpleView()
```

Still when I submit the form nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

============SOLVED=============
render function was not adding the template to view's el

Comment: you're right. i edited the submit function. i had some more lines. for example this console.log i don't see happening

Comment: It's your view who generate the form html ?

Comment: yes. the view I posted is in fact simple.hbs

Comment: Make sure you're calling `event.preventDefault()` at the top of your submit handler otherwise the form will simply submit through the browser normally.

Comment: @idbehold this does not work either. I'm thinking form needs an action?

Comment: Yeah, and maybe an `type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be listening for the event properly (i.e. not sure the `submit` event will propagate to the view level, which is where you're listening). Try listening to the form submit:

```
events:
  'submit form': 'submit'
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be it